# Local or push notifications for Android IOS app in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an application developed in Flutter, and I have a doubt about a process that I should incorporate into the application, I should incorporate local or push notifications that depend on a Mysql database, I thought of using local with workmanager and the api, but they are not so precise since these notifications depend on data stored in the database, such as date and time. In addition, the workmanager gives me a horrible debug notification, that is, I don't like it, I think the library generates it. .. So I would use push notifications combined with firebase, but should I have a separate server to do this job, send notifications like twitter or facebook to my app?